# Figure short caption in LOF in Quarto

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

What is the Quarto way to write an alternative caption for the LOF?

Tex code would be like:

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{img/some_image.png}
  \caption[Short caption for LOF.]{A long and descriptive caption to be shown below figure. Source: somebody}
  \label{fig:figure-1}
\end{figure}
```

## EDIT: STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. new Quarto file
2. a picture in /img/some_image.png

### CONTENTS OF QUARTO FILE

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
lof: true
---

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{img/some_image.png}
  \caption[Short caption for LOF.]{A long and descriptive caption to be shown below figure. Source: somebody}
  \label{fig:figure-1}
\end{figure}
```

### RESULTS

[image: LOF]

[image: Image with caption]

### WHAT DO I WANT INSTEAD

A "Quarto way", like:

```
![A long and descriptive caption to be shown below figure. Source: somebody.][Short caption for LOF.](img/some_image.png)
```

Comment: Could you please share a working reproducible example?

Comment: @Quinten kinda straightfoward but here it is

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "kinda straightforward", particularly if it removes ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fig-scap`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html#figures) option to get a short caption in the "List of Figures". From the Quarto docs,

> `fig-scap` => A short caption (only used in LaTeX output). A short caption is inserted in `\caption[]`, and usually displayed in the “List of Figures” of a PDF document.

```
---
title: Demo Short Figure Caption
format: pdf
lof: true
---

## Quarto

![A long and descriptive caption.](test-scap.png){#fig-short-cap fig-scap="Short caption for LOF." width=30%}
```

---

[image: short caption for figures in quarto]